# MS SQL 2012 , Updating mistake record has another session

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, transactions, scope-identity

I have an ASP.NET system with multiuser using MS SQL server 2012. I have an confusing problem .I have an table like

*ID* *Name* *MasterID* *Count*

Now.Suppose that , There is **User1** and **User2**. User1 and User2 insert record over screen which has use stored procedure at the same time. Procedure return inserted ID like

> ...
>   SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY();

For example User1's inserted record is 379 and User2's inserted record is 380. Both of user must update MasterID in their own record soon by ID. But  sometimes User2 update User1 record. What can cause this error. Thanks for your help

Comment: Don't use `SCOPE_IDENTITY()`.  Use the `OUTPUT` clause to get the new ids:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql.

Comment: Take a look here https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2019779/you-may-receive-incorrect-values-when-using-scope-identity-and-identity

Comment: @Hexxx , I have read article. But this problem occurs in MS 2008 and earlier version. I am using MS 2012